# Synchronize the state of validation for custom control with inner PrimeNG control in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, primeng

I am trying to create a wrapper object around an PrimeNG Calendar control and after years not developing with Angular I still have to note, that there is no easy way in extending a control and all it's control-functionality.

What I want is, that the necessary functionality (like setting the validation state, eg. "ng-pristine" or "ng-dirty") is passed to the inner control. But that doesn't work correctly. Maybe there is someone, who has solved this problem!

```
const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CalendarFieldComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'calendar-field',
  templateUrl: './calendar-field.component.html',
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR],

})
export class CalendarFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {

  @Input() required = false;
  @ViewChild(NgModel) model?: NgModel;

  private innerValue: any = '';

  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

  private onValidatorChange: (_: any) => void = noop;

  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  };

  set value(v: any) {
    console.log(this.model);
    this.model?.control.markAsDirty();
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
      this.onChangeCallback(v);
    }
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.onTouchedCallback();
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return {'required': true};
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onValidatorChange = fn;
  }
}
```

The template looks like the following:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" styleClass="inputfield w-full" appendTo="body" [required]="required" (blur)="onBlur()"></p-calendar>
```

When I have a FormGroup which contains the control above. When the Form is submitted, I want to validate all field, which already works by using the following code. All the empty fields have a red border (because of ng-invalid), except for the wrapped controls.

```
// code which validates all the fields when clicking on submit button
private validateForm(): boolean {
    for (const controlKey of Object.keys(this.form.controls)) {
        const control = this.form.controls[controlKey];
        control.markAllAsTouched();
        control.markAsDirty();
        control.markAsTouched();
    }
    return !!this.form.valid;
}
```

The wrapper control gets the classes "ng-invalid ng-touched ng-dirty" whereas the inner control just get the classes "ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted".

How can I synchronize this (from wrapper to inner)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this to sync the errors from the inner control with the outer control

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return {'required': this.validateForm()};
}
```

To achieve the other way around (set error on the inner control) I do something like this:

```
const ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl).control;
ngControl.statusChanges.pipe(filter(x => x === 'INVALID' || x === 'VALID' )).subscribe(_ => this.setInputErrors())

setInputErrors(): void {
    const ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl).control;
    if (ngControl.invalid) {
        this.innerFormControl.setErrors( { incorrect: true });
    else {
        this.innerFormControl.setErrors(null);
    }
}
```

For this solution, I'm using a reactive forms approach instead of template driven. This works in most cases for me, but you would probably make some changes.

Comment: I was hoping, that there is a more functioning way to retrieve the NgControl. At least in template driven forms, it is really difficult to get the control and it is also impossible in my case to set or retrieve a control of the PrimeNG component. It seems like, I have to live with the fact, that a "tree of inputs" cannot be synced. But thanks for your approach.

Comment: What is wrong with switching to reactive form in this scenario?

Comment: It's just too much effort (I have multiple large forms in the app) and I don't have the feeling, that everything will just work afterwards. Maybe I still cannot get the FormControl. Currently I could eventually get the FormControl from ControlContainer and the Input('name'). But the formGroup is not available when ngOnInit is fired. Also not in AfterViewInit. Not sure, if that would be another case with Reactive forms.